# What does "leveling" mean in a time series?

Tags: time-series, terminology

In time series forecasting methods, what does it mean for the series to be "leveled?"

Comment: Please cite where this is used.

Comment: It is used in an example if Rob J Hyndman's text on methods used for forecasting in business applications. [http://www.robjhyndman.com/papers/businessforecasting.pdf](link to pdf)

Comment: Are you sure it was some form of the verb "to level" (if such one exists) rather than a noun "level"? Noun "level" is indeed used in time series literature, but I have not seen the verb used there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the text you linked, I searched for "level" and found only one occurrence:

> Forecasts are given by $\hat{y}_{t+h|t} = l_t + hb_t$ where
>
> > $l_t = \alpha y_t + (1-\alpha)(l_{t-1} + b_{t-1})$
> >
> > $b_t = \beta(l_t-l_{t-1})+(1-\beta)b_{t-1}$
>
> Here $l_t$ denotes the level of the series and $b_t$ the slope of the trend at time $t$.

Is this what you were referring to? Level simply means the current value of the series at time $t$, after some exponential smoothing.  ($y_t$ is the level or current value of the series without exponential smoothing.)

Comment: Ok thanks, that's actually exactly what I was wondering, it may have been a simple question but I was stumped haha.